# Misleading tag hovering over featured company appears to click a tag but really goes to company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the featured company section there is a set of tags.  I don't think the hover effect should happen on these tags.  When you hover over the tags it appears the tags are clickable.  When you do click them it actually opens the company page rather than what the user would expect.

I propose that these remain constant with no style change on hover and clicking any of that area could take you to the company page.  Otherwise I think this could be misleading:

[image]

Comment: Crap. I said NO dark pattern garbage...gettin' this looked at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Jon. I've removed the hover style there.